# IOMMU Emulation and install with QEMU

Tags: io, qemu, emulation, kvm, mmu

For now, I need to use some packages to do a emulation for IOMMU (it is similar to MMU), and I got some source about it, but I don't know how to use them.

http://www.spinics.net/lists/kvm/msg38514.html Here is a link of source for emulating IOMMU

http://repo.or.cz/w/qemu-kvm/amd-iommu.git Here is a link for downloading file for this emulation

My problem is how to use qemu to do this and there are so many file in the download list, I don't know how to use them...

Thanks for your help, really appreciate!!!  If you know something detail, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use download option in the right side of the page ( Generally snapshot option is available in repositories )
[or this](http://repo.or.cz/w/qemu-kvm/amd-iommu.git/snapshot/87d609eb1dd390eaa45a4d29f9aadf44f5e2379f.tar.gz)

then simply use configure script to generate makefile 
i.e.

use `ccache` if you want to recompile it again and again

```
$CC="ccache gcc"./configure --prefix=$PREFIX <br>
```

then make to build and install, use `-j<no_of_cpu+1>`

```
$make -j5 all install
```

if you have dependencies issue, solve them using `synaptic manager` or `apt-get`

P.S. AFAIK You should have iommu support available in hardware, if you have 64-bit machine then you might have. You can check flags in using `cat /proc/cpuinfo`